# How to access nested JSON object with strings as keys

Tags: node.js

OK so I have a JSON file that has a format similar to the following:

```
{
    "basePath": "/",
    "paths": {
        "/x1/v1/something": {
            "set": {
                "summary": "Get something",
                "tags": ["event"]
        }, ................
}
```

I need to access the "tags" element of the JSON object.

So I load the JSON like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var JSONobj = require("/Users/petersons/Desktop/swagger.json");
```

If I know I can access "/x1/v1/something" by doing:

```
for(var object in JSONobj.paths) {
  console.log(object);
}
```

But I don't understand how to go further down the rabbit hole since those properties are dynamic strings.

Answer (score -2):

Just keep looping with the key you get each iteration:

```
for (var key in JSONobj.paths) {
    if (typeof JSONobj.paths[key] === "object" && JSONobj.paths[key] !== null) {
        for (var secondKey in JSONobj.paths[key]) {
             console.log(JSONobj.paths[key][secondKey]);
             //Do another check and loop over secondKey if needed, so on so forth
             //Do some checking for the specific key that you want
        }
    } else {
        console.log(JSONobj.paths[key]);
    }
}
```